# Is it possible to add percentages to a contingency table

Tags: r

I have a question about the `table()` function in R. I want to add an extra column to show percentages from counts made by `table()`. I have a data frame like this:

```
delta=data.frame(x1=c("x001","x001","x002","x002","x001","x001","x002"),x2=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1))
```

When I compute `table()` for this data frame I got this:

```
table(delta$x1,delta$x2)

       1 2
  x001 3 1
  x002 3 0
```

It is possible to add percentages in this table or there is any function or package in R to compute something like this:

```
       1 2  Number Percentage
  x001 3 1    4     0.5714286
  x002 3 0    3     0.4285714
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick solution using `sum()` and `rowSums()`:

```
> tbl <- table(delta)
> (tbl <- cbind(tbl, rowSums(tbl), rowSums(tbl) / sum(tbl)))

     1 2        
x001 3 1 4 0.571
x002 3 0 3 0.429
```

And you can add column names with `colnames()`; e.g.:

```
> colnames(tbl) <- c("1", "2", "N", "Pct")
> tbl
     1 2 N   Pct
x001 3 1 4 0.571
x002 3 0 3 0.429
```

Comment: can also add some of the column names with `cbind(tbl, Sums=rowSums(tbl), Pct=` ...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `prop.table` and `addmargins`

```
tbl <- table(delta$x1,delta$x2)

prop.table(tbl)

# 1         2
# x001 0.4285714 0.1428571 
# x002 0.4285714 0.0000000

addmargins(tbl)

# 1 2 Sum
# x001 3 1   4
# x002 3 0   3
# Sum  6 1   7
```

**EDIT**

Of course you can do something like

```
rowSums(prop.table(tbl)) 
     x001      x002 
0.5714286 0.4285714
```

But my answer is to say that there are some built-in function in R that complete the `table` function.

Comment: I dont see how prop.table would solve the OP's issues on it's own.   You still have to sum over the results, no?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta you can add `rowSums`..and the question is to about any function in R that compute something `like` this... I hope that my answer is clear after the edit.

Comment: I follow you that you can sum up prop.table.  I just dont think that `prop.table` and `addmargins` go well together for this answer.   ie, you cannot do `cbind(addmargins(tbl), rowSums(prop.table(tbl)))`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta no Try this for example `cbind(addmargins(tbl,2),rowSums(prop.table(tbl)))`. But this is not important, as I said previously, my answer is mainly to see to the OP that such functions exist. ( Thanks to be rigorous)

Answer (score 2):

the calculations are not very tricky.
What might be tripping you up is that that table does not convert directly to a data.frame.  At least not how you might want it to.   Here is a break down, step by step.

```
# this is the basic table, we want it as a data.frame
delCounts <- table(delta)

# you need to convert the table to a matrix, before converting to a data.frame
results <- data.frame(matrix(delCounts, nrow=nrow(delCounts)))

# you may want to preserve the names.  Have a look: 
dimnames(delCounts)  # first are the column names, then row names

colnames(results) <- dimnames(delCounts)[[1]]
rownames(results) <- dimnames(delCounts)[[2]]

# Now sum up and take percentages
# we can use vectorized arithmetic operations for the percentage
results$Number <- rowSums(results)
results$Percentage <- results$Number / sum(results$Number)

# we might want to round instead
results$Percentage <- round(results$Number / sum(results$Number)*100, 2)

results
#   x001 x002 Number Percentage
# 1    3    1      4      57.14
# 2    3    0      3      42.86
```